# Angular Router bounces between routes

Tags: angular, routes

In my angular 4 app I have a sidenav component that handles my routes. In each route I have promises that are called. When I switch the route before all the promises are resolved, the router will bounce between the two selected routes, reloading the pages and making the same API calls, over and over. Any Idea why the route keeps getting called or the router navigates back to a page that I clicked off of to load the new page?

```
<ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content">
        <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a [routerLink]="['/pending']" ><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>Pending Users</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a [routerLink]="['/users']" ><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Edit Users</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a [routerLink]="['/shipinfo']" >
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>Ship Information</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a [routerLink]="['/systemconfig']"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i>System Configuration</a>
        </li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
            <a [routerLink]="['/search']"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search Users</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any guards that would cause redirects between the two routes? Do you promises navigate to a route after they are resolved?

Comment: @LLai Yes we do use guards on the routes, and no on the navigation after the promises are resolved

Comment: Can you post the guards and promises code?